# Why is my figure not rendering in elsarticle? I just see the text instead

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, elsarticle

I am having a really bizarre error using the [elsarticle](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elsevier-article-elsarticle-template/vdzfjgjbckgz) template in overleaf. When I try to enter a figure into my draft paper as

```
 \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{MyImage.png}
\end{figure}
```

It is instead just showing my the filename text in a box (image below).
[image]

Why would this be happening and how can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: looks like you enabled draft mode (or the image is not found, but then you would have an error as well as that output

Comment: I thought as much but this seems to be a default behavior on elsarticle. I don't see a \usepackage(graphics) command anywhere in the .cls file. How do I disable draft mode and why on earth would elsevier make this behavior default? I have not changed anything from the template itself.  Thanks so much for the response!

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior of elsarticle for some reason. In the main text file there are some options

```
%%\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the option review to obtain double line spacing
%% \documentclass[authoryear,preprint,review,12pt]{elsarticle}

%% Use the options 1p,twocolumn; 3p; 3p,twocolumn; 5p; or 5p,twocolumn
%% for a journal layout:
\documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

I had my option set to preprint which was causing this issue by setting graphics to draft mode. It can be disabled by selecting another documentclass option.